# How to pass complex object from JSON (REST call) to Yaml azure devops

Tags: json, azure-devops, yaml, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have an azure devops pipeline where I declare the following parameter:

```
parameters:
  - name: extra_tags
    displayName: Extra tags to add
    type: object
    default:
      foo: "bar"
      two: "three"
```

And it fails when I to trigger the pipeline via Http REST with the following body:

```
{
    "resources": {
        "repositories": {
            "self": {
                "refName": "refs/heads/main"
            }
        }
    },
    "templateParameters": {
        "extra_tags": {
            "1": "one",
            "2": "two"
        }
    }
}
```

If I remove the extra_tags, it works, since I declared the default, has anyone faced such problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure DevOps YAML Pipeline Parameters Not Working from REST API Trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60852825/azure-devops-yaml-pipeline-parameters-not-working-from-rest-api-trigger)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try using the following Request body:

```
{
    "resources": {
        "repositories": {
            "self": {
                "refName": "refs/heads/main"
            }
        }
    },
    "templateParameters": {
        "extra_tags": "1: one\n2: two"
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you know? :)